# How do I insert into multiple linked tables at once, in SQLite3 and Python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am making a library system for a school project and I am having trouble inserting new books in my system and having the primary keys in each table (which are foreign keys for other tables) update at the same time, my database tables are as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE `authorTable` (
    `authorID`  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `firstName` TEXT,
    `lastName`  TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE `bookInfo` (
    `infoID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `title` TEXT,
    `description`   TEXT,
    `authorID`  INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(`authorID`) REFERENCES `authorTable`(`authorID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `isbnInfo` (
    `isbn`  INTEGER,
    `infoID`    INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(`isbn`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`infoID`) REFERENCES `bookInfo`(`infoID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `bookTable` (
    `bookID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `available` INTEGER,
    `isbn`  INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(`isbn`) REFERENCES `isbnInfo`(`isbn`)
);
```

Currently I am completely lost and not know how to even begin making this work, my current code is:

```
def addBook(self, bookTitle, bookDesc, bookAuthorFirstName, bookAuthorLastName, bookISBN, add_book_window, aor_window):
    bookTitle = bookTitle.get()
    bookDesc = bookDesc.get()
    bookAuthorFirstName = bookAuthorFirstName.get()
    bookAuthorLastName = bookAuthorLastName.get()
    bookISBN = bookISBN.get()
    if len(bookTitle) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Book Title")
    elif len(bookDesc) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Book Description")
    elif len(bookAuthorFirstName) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Book Author's First Name")
    elif len(bookAuthorLastName) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Book Author's Last Name")
    elif len(bookISBN) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Book ISBN")
    else:
        try:
            bookISBN = int(bookISBN)
        except:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "ISBN must be all numbers!")
        with sqlite3.connect("library.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
```

I am using Tkinter in Python and the parameters used in the function above come from:

```
    ### ADD BOOK CONTENT (for add_book) add_book_window

    bookTitle = StringVar()
    bookDesc = StringVar()
    bookAuthorFirstName = StringVar()
    bookAuthorLastName = StringVar()
    bookISBN = StringVar()

    Label(add_book_window, text='Book Title: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=217)
    Label(add_book_window, text='Book Description: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=237)         
    Label(add_book_window, text='Author First Name: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=257)
    Label(add_book_window, text='Author Last Name: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=277)        
    Label(add_book_window, text='ISBN: ', bg = self.bgc, fg = "grey", font = "Arial").place(x=315, y=297)

    Entry(add_book_window, textvariable = bookTitle, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=220)
    Entry(add_book_window, textvariable = bookDesc, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=240)
    Entry(add_book_window, textvariable = bookAuthorFirstName, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=260)
    Entry(add_book_window, textvariable = bookAuthorLastName, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=280)        
    Entry(add_book_window, textvariable = bookISBN, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=300)      

    Entry(edit_account_window, textvariable = bookTitle, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=220)
    Entry(edit_account_window, textvariable = bookDesc, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=240)
    Entry(edit_account_window, textvariable = bookAuthorFirstName, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=260)
    Entry(edit_account_window, textvariable = bookAuthorLastName, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=260)
    Entry(edit_account_window, textvariable = bookISBN, bg = 'light grey').place(x=450, y=280)        

    addBook = Button(add_book_window, text='Add Book', width = 11, command=lambda:self.addBook(bookTitle, bookDesc, bookAuthorFirstName, bookAuthorLastName, bookISBN, add_book_window, aor_window)) # ADDS BOOK TO LIST
    addBook.place(x=468, y=325)
```

Help with how my function should look like would be great! Not sure how to use SQL queries to make everything work and add a new book to the database so that it will update all tables at once.

And if there is already a book with an author Name and Surname that matches an author Name and Surname in the author table, to keep that same author ID and just update the other parts, and if I add a book with an ISBN matching that of a book with the same ISBN in the isbn table already, to use the same bookInfo, authorInfo, and isbn info and just update the bookTable (where each individual book (even if there are x amount of a same book) is listed with unique bookID).

Comment: This feels like a "fix it for me" question, and as such is likely to be regarded as too broad by readers here. Can you narrow it down to a more specific problem?

Comment: Didn't mean for it to come across that way, but honestly speaking I am unsure of how to even begin so asking I am asking for someone to guide me in the right way, I know how to insert data into tables one by one, and I saw posts on how to do it to multiple tables, but I couldn't find any specific way to do what I need to do, which is update the tables linked simultaneously by foreign keys appropriately, having each foreign key ID update simultaneously etc.

Comment: In general with relational databases, data is not inserted into different tables simultaneously. Just insert it into each table one at a time. If a foreign key depends on an auto-generated primary key created by an insert, then your real (and only necessary) question is to work out how to get the auto-incremented PK.

Comment: It is true you can wrap many database operations in a transaction (and SQLite does support that) but don't do that for now - get it working first.